# xslt-1.0 depth first pre-order traversal numbering

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am looking for an identity transform that adds an ordering attribute to each node. I want to have the explicit document position of each node available as an integer number.

I believe the desired ordering (as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#/media/File:Sorted_binary_tree_preorder.svg) is the default ordering indeed as a selection on the descendants axis produces the correct ordering numbers:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method='xml' encoding='utf-8' indent='yes'/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
 <root>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::*">
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:attribute name="doc_order">
   <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I need to preserve the input document structure as well,
as code above generates a flat list of all nodes instead.

```html
example input:
<root>
 <f>
  <b>
   <a/>
   <d>
    <c/>
    <e/>
   </d>
  </b>
 </f>
 <g>
  <i>
   <h/>
  </i>
 </g>
</root>

desired output with explicit document order:
<root>
 <f doc_order="1">
  <b doc_order="2">
   <a doc_order="3"/>
   <d doc_order="4">
    <c doc_order="5"/>
    <e doc_order="6"/>
   </d>
  </b>
 </f>
 <g doc_order="7">
  <i doc_order="8">
   <h doc_order="9"/>
  </i>
 </g>
</root>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of input XML that you are working on, and the output you expect? Thanks!

Comment: yeah, thanks for asking, there it goes!

Answer (score 0):

Learn about `xsl:number`, it is powerful:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*//*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="doc_order">
      <xsl:number level="any" count="*" from="root"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See http://xsltransform.net/94rmq6n for an online sample.

Comment: i was just reading http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-number :)
the thing is xsl:number explodes in complexity on real-life xml files (think ~minutes), it does the computation on every node again and again, I'm looking for some sort of accumulator here

Comment: Is that opinion that "xsl:number explodes in complexity" based on measurement with a certain XSLT processor? As for accumulators, they come in XSLT 3.0.

Comment: I've measured xsltproc here:
xsltproc --timing ord.xslt data.xml > /dev/null
Parsing stylesheet ord.xslt took 0 ms
Parsing document data.xml took 163 ms
Applying stylesheet took 251082 ms
Saving result took 60 ms

identity transform on same file takes 463 ms

i does make sense at least to me, given what xsl:number is designed for - it does creating lists of numbers from ancestor nodes and formats them then

accumulator> I'm not sure I use the established naming here, I've seen a pattern where you couple the traversal with a param that you increment on every template invocation

Comment: Let's see what others have to suggest as answers or comments.

Comment: As an alternative, try whether `    <xsl:attribute name="doc_order">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::* | preceding::*)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>` performs better with xsltproc.